# What is the behavior when sum of widths of columns != table width?

Tags: html, width, css-tables

I have a table with a fixed width of 800.

I noticed that when the column widths don't add up to 800, my browser (Chrome) will arbitrarily choose one column to increase in size (could be more than one, I'm not sure).

Also, when I make the sum of the widths of the columns > 800, then it just accepts it.

Is there a standard behavior of how a browser should behave when the sum of the widths of the columns do not equal the width of the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be proper behavior.

According to the spec, user agents (browsers) are directed to "reflow" columns as necessary

> If column widths prove to be too narrow for the contents of a
>   particular table cell, user agents may choose to reflow the table.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#column-width

Also,

> User agents may use any algorithm they wish to do so, and are free to
>   prefer rendering speed over precision, except when the "fixed layout
>   algorithm" is selected.

See more here

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout

Comment: Hooray! More links to the real thing to push the w3fools out of the way. I think I fixed the fragment on your first link, you might want to double check it though.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort!  Appreciate the link fix.  Yes, it is the correct link.  Goodbye w3fools!

Comment: Thank you both!  This was exactly the information plus the source that I was looking for!

Comment: @steve8918: the W3 standards are actually pretty readable with a little practice with standardeze, just include `site:w3.org` in your googl searches to find them.